# How to check how hard an object hits the ground and create an explosive "force" around it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics, physics

Recently I have started my first 2D game project on unity and everything has been going well. My only problem so far is with my enemy. My enemy, when attacking, jumps in the air and then falls and hits the ground. I want my script to detect when it falls and how hard it falls then create a force that pushes the player back as if its an "explosion."

So my questions are how do I detect the enemy hitting the ground, after a fall, and then add a force?

I tried using onCollisionEnter2D on Unity but it does not work since technically even when the enemy is moving it's still "falling."

Here is my attempt at checking if the enemy fell then searching for the player and calling the explosion force function.

```
        private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
        {
            if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
            {
                foreach (Collider2D Obj in Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, radius))
                {
                    if (Obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() != null && Obj.gameObject != gameObject)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Calling Function");
                        Rigidbody2D rb = Obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
                        ExplosionForce2D forceScript = GetComponent<ExplosionForce2D>();
                        forceScript.AddExplosionForce(rb, force, transform.position, radius);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This is my code for adding a force to the object.

```
        public void AddExplosionForce (Rigidbody2D body, float expForce, Vector3 expPosition, float expRadius)
        {
            var dir = (body.transform.position - expPosition);
            float calc = 1 - (dir.magnitude / expRadius);
            if (calc <= 0) {
                calc = 0;       
            }

            body.AddForce (dir.normalized * expForce * calc);
        }
```

I expect that, if the player is in the enemy radius, and the enemy jumps, falls, and hits the floor it will push the player back as if it was an explosion.

Comment: How about using the velocity of the player? Then use it as a multiplier for the explosion force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a flag that can check that if the enemy is falling or not, so when your enemy is actually falling set this as **true**, if not (means moving) then set as **false.**

Checking for Velocity is a good solution.
So you can do like,

```
body.velocity.magnitude

// magnitude to remove the direction issue.
// now apply all this as 
body.AddForce(dir.normalized * expForce * calc * body.velocity.magnitude);
```